# Enable CORS Globally in Java

Tags: java, spring

I am using java to write a servlet and from Spring.io, this code snippet

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

enables CORS globally. Please where do i place this class?

Comment: not sure, what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

That is a Spring `@Configuration` class. Assuming you're using code-based configuration (most modern projects do), place the class anywhere that it will be component-scanned, or `@Import` it from your root configuration.

Comment: meaning i can place it in my Application class?

Answer (score 1):

you can place this class inside any package, by annotation itself spring will know through component-scan